# Showing that $\exp(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nX^n)=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\exp(a_nX^n)$ for formal power series

Tags: power-series, exponentiation, formal-power-series

I've just come across [formal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series) power series and am not very fluent with them yet.

I'd like to show that $\exp(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nX^n)=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\exp(a_nX^n)$.

Can anybody help?

Comment: This identity holds modulo $X^N$ for all $N$.

Comment: @Simeon Oh of course! I feel so stupid. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

$$\exp\left(\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_n X^n\right)=\exp\left({\lim\limits_{n\to 
+\infty}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}a_k X^k}\right)=\lim\limits_{n \to +\infty}\exp \left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}a_k X^k\right)=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n}\exp \left(a_k X^k\right)=\\=\prod\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}\exp \left(a_n X^n\right)  $$
We changed $\lim$ and $\exp$ because of the fact that $\exp x$ is continuous

Comment: Okay great thanks. Do you have a proof or reference that exp is continuous in the formal power series ring?

Comment: As I know, $|\exp x -\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\frac{x^k}{k!}|<\varepsilon$, and usually one considers $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_n x^n$ as a continuous function where the series converges, and the series for exp converges everywhere

Comment: You'd better have $a_0=0$ for this to make sense, even with formal power series.

Comment: @Paul I'm considering $\exp$ as a function on the [formal power series ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series). So I'm considering $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nX^n$ as a variable, not a function itself. I think your answer above runs through fine so long as $\exp$ is continuous. I imagine it is!

Comment: Thanks @Ted, do you know if there's a way to make it work when $a_0 \neq 0$? In particular I'm interested in the case $a_0=1$.

Comment: Sure, @Matt, use $e^{x+y} = e^x e^y$ to pull the $e^{a_0}$ out and then you're left with a formal power series that makes sense. (In particular, you only have to sum a finite number of terms to get the coefficient of $X^n$. This would not be true if you had $a_0$ in there.)

Comment: Thanks @Ted. If I'm understanding you correctly you're saying that the exponential function is only defined on formal series with $a_0=0$. If $a_0 \neq 0$ then, for example, the coefficient of X would be $\sum n a_0^{n-1} a_1$ which may not be in the ring. This kind of thing won't be a problem if $a_0 =0$. However we could expand the exponential function's domain to include those series with $a_0 \neq 0$ using the trick you've just mentioned. Then the formula above holds for those series including those with $a_0 \neq 0$ if and only if it holds for those with $a_0=0$. Is that right?

Comment: Seems right to me. The point is that to compose formal power series, you would like finite (or at least convergent!) sums for each coefficient.

Comment: @Ted that makes sense. Do you have a proof that the formula in question holds when $a_0=0$?

Comment: Matt: It should reduce to the "usual" proof based on power series expansions that $e^{x+y} = e^xe^y$.